# Can I assign an input prompt to a variable?

Tags: python, f-string

This is my code:

```
print(f" the int of your number is {int(float(input('type in a number: ')))}")
```

Is there a way to assign a variable based on `{int(float(input('type in a number: ')))}` so that I can re-use it?

Comment: Even if this _does_ work, _**please don't**_. [Readability counts](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: Why would you want to? Why not just use assignment on a line before the `print()`?

Comment: And no, there is no way you can do that, because even with Python 3, the walrus assignment expression can't be used in an f-string.

Comment: thanks!! it might be not so useful but i did wanted to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do it in two steps:

```
float_answer = float(input('type in a number: '))
print(f" the int of your number is {int(float_answer)}")
```